# Infer new inputs from model trained with the Tensorflow Dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow

I train a tensorflow (1.7) model from a Dataset API as follows:

```
features_data_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None, max_sent_len], 'features_data_ph')

mode_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name='mode_ph')

labels_data_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, num_classes], 'labels_data_ph')

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_data_ph, labels_data_ph))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100000).batch(batch_size)
train_iterator = train_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_data_ph, labels_data_ph))
val_iterator = val_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

input_tensor, labels_tensor = tf.case(
                {
                    tf.equal(mode_ph, 0): train_iter.get_next,
                    tf.equal(mode_ph, 1): val_iter.get_next,
                }
            )

logits = model(input_tensor)
loss = get_loss(logits, labels_tensor)
...
# start of training epoch
session.run(train_iterator.initializer, feed_dict={
    features_data_ph: train_features,
    labels_data_ph: train_labels
})
...
# new validation after some steps
session.run(val_iterator.initializer, feed_dict={
    features_data_ph: val_features,
    labels_data_ph: val_labels
})
```

Now as you can see, `input_tensor` depends on the dataset. So I can't just feed a new numpy array to infer data which is not in the dataset.

What I have done so far is create a **3rd dataset** meant to hold inference data (and add `tf.equal(mode_ph, 2): infer_iter.get_next` to `tf.case`)

**Is there a better way to infer data not held in an existing dataset?** Using the `val_dataset` would overwrite the data it contains

Comment: What error did you get when you fed a NumPy array for `input_tensor`?

Comment: I don't get an error, I can't give it a value as it is not a placeholder but the result of `iterator.get_next()`

Comment: You should be able to feed a value for the tensor(s) returned from an `iterator.get_next()` call. In general, almost any tensor can be fed with a value of the same shape and type. (There are exceptions for tensors created inside `tf.cond()` and `tf.while_loop()`.) If you get an error saying the tensor is "not feedable", you can create a [`tf.placeholder_with_default()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder_with_default), which gives you a placeholder that can be fed, but that takes a default value if you don't feed it.

Comment: I hope you're right but I can't assign a value to this tensor, as `session.run(input_tensor.assign(some_numpy_values))` throws an error `'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'`

Comment: Also, using a default value for an inference process which inherently varies seems weird, I'm not sure where this would be going if I do 2 inferences in a row